# Trying to get MuiThemeProvider gives errors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui

The error is: MuiThemeProvider(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null. im not familiar with material ui so i opened the terminal and rad 'npm i --save-dev material-ui', it installed and said something about having updated. then i wrote the code in myc1.js and the imports in app.js here are my two files of code from webstorm:

app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import CoolButton from './components/myc1.js';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            inp: 'Hello type your text here',
            gender: 'm',
            textInput: ''
        }
    }
    handleSubmit (event){
         console.log('form has been submitted');
            event.preventDefault();
    }
    handleChange (e){
        console.log('in input there is: '+e.target.value);
        this.setState({textInput: e.target.value})
    }
  render() {
            const change = () => {
                this.setState({inp: this.refs.var.value });
            };
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input ref="var1" value={this.state.inp} onChange={
              change
          }/>
          <br />
          Gender: Male
          <input type='radio' name="Gender"
                 onChange={()=> this.setState({gender: 'm'}) }
                 checked={ this.state.gender === 'm'}
          />
          Female
          <input type='radio' name="Gender"
                        onChange={()=> this.setState({gender: 'f'}) }
                        checked={ this.state.gender === 'f'}
      />
          {this.state.gender}
          <form onSubmit={App.handleSubmit}>
              <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
              <button type="submit">Send</button>
          </form>
            <MuiThemeProvider />
          <CoolButton/>
                <MuiThemeProvider/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

here is myc1.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const CoolButton = () => (
<RaisedButton label="Default" />

);

export default CoolButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of:

```
 <MuiThemeProvider />
   <CoolButton/>
 <MuiThemeProvider/>
```

you want:

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
  <CoolButton/>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```